# how to provide I2C function with flags for SI7021 diagram on EFR32

Tags: embedded

the diagram bellow shows the I2C comminucation with the Controller master.
From the API shown bellow i have the following command which needs to be provided with flags to  act as the diagram .
I am not femiliar with proving flags to I2C_trnasfer.
How its done?
Thanks.

I2C_Transfer (I2C_TypeDef *i2c)

https://docs.silabs.com/mcu/5.4/efr32fg14/group-I2C

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is just a rough starting point for you.  You'll have to experiment and work out any kinks.

This [EFR32 I2C documentation](https://siliconlabs.github.io/Gecko_SDK_Doc/efr32mg1/html/group__I2C.html) says you have to call `I2C_TransferInit()` to setup the transfer.  You could try setting up a single transfer with `seq->flags = I2C_FLAG_WRITE_READ`.  But I suspect that method will not handle a NACK from the slave while the measurement is in progress.  So this code splits it into two transfers.  The first transfer writes the measurement command.  The second transfer reads the measured value.  And the second transfer is repeated if a NACK is received because the slave measurement is in progress.

You'll have to supply values for `MEASURE_CMD` and `SLAVE_ADDRESS`.  But the `I2C_FLAG_*` values are defined in the EFR32's em_i2c.h.

```
I2C_TransferSeq_TypeDef *seq;
I2C_TransferReturn_TypeDef ret;

// Write the measure command.
uint8_t meas_cmd = MEASURE_CMD;
seq->addr = SLAVE_ADDRESS;
seq->flags = I2C_FLAG_WRITE;
seq->buf[0].data = &meas_cmd;
seq->buf[0].len = 1;
ret = I2C_TransferInit(I2C0, seq);
while (ret == i2cTransferInProgress)
{
  ret = I2C_Transfer(I2C0);
}

// If the write was successful
if (ret == i2cTransferDone)
{
  // Read the measured value.
  uint8_t meas_val_bytes[2];
  seq->addr = SLAVE_ADDRESS;
  seq->flags = I2C_FLAG_READ;
  seq->buf[0].data = &meas_val_bytes[0];
  seq->buf[0].len = 2;

  // The intention of this do-while loop is to repeat the I2C_TransferInit() if the slave NACKs the read request.
  do
  {
    ret = I2C_TransferInit(I2C0, seq);
    while (ret == i2cTransferInProgress)
    {
      ret = I2C_Transfer(I2C0);
    }
  } while (ret == i2cTransferNack);

  // If the read was successful
  if (ret == i2cTransferDone)
  {
    // The first byte received is the most significant byte.
    uint16_t measured_value = (meas_val_bytes[0] << 8) + meas_val_bytes[1];
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello ,i am trying to visualise in your code the order of the diagram.
in our diagram we send address and command from the master to the slave and the slave acklowledged both of them.Where is it happening in the code?

Comment: @rocko445, The acknowledgement is part of the I2C protocol, just like the Start (S) and Stop (P) bits.  These protocol details are handled by the I2C hardware peripheral and the `I2C_Transfer` functions.  The EFR32's I2C library API abstracts those protocol details away so that your application can focus on the bigger picture.

Comment: Your application provides the slave address, transfer type, and transfer buffers in the `seq` struct passed to `I2C_TransferInit()`.  Then the `I2C_Transfer` functions and the I2C hardware peripheral take care of the details like start, stop, and acknowledgements.  If a NACK occurs during the transfer then the `I2C_Transfer` functions return the NACK status so your application can take the appropriate action.

Comment: One thing that is different between my example code and the diagram is the repeat start bit (Sr).  My code performs two separate transfers, each with a start and stop.  So my code replaces the repeat start bit with a stop and new start.

Comment: You would have to use the I2C_FLAG_WRITE_READ transfer type to get a repeat start bit.  (And then you would also have to initialize both buffers in `seq->buf`.)  But I doubt that the I2C_FLAG_WRITE_READ transfer type will handle the NACK during the read portion.  I expect it will end the transfer with NACK status rather than attempt to repeat the read.  So I split the transfer up into two transfers and added that do-while loop to repeat the read if necessary.

Comment: My code does not attempt to get the checksum value.  You could get the checksum by increasing the size of the `meas_val_bytes[]` definition to 3 and increasing the read length to 3.  Then after the read is successful the checksum value should be in `meas_val_bytes[2]`.